# Responsive SVG path without distorting stroke

Tags: svg, path, stroke, responsive-design

I have a simple SVG path with a stroke that I want to responsively resize with the browser window. The problem is that when my paths aspect ratio is changed, the stroke is distorted.

This is the original path on the left and the distorted shape on the right:

[image]

Live example (resize your browser): http://codepen.io/Cai_/pen/pyBobP

I need the rectangle to be one single path with a stroke so I can animate `stroke-dashoffset` / `stroke-dasharray` etc.

I could use javascript to update the path but I would like to know if there is a way to do this with pure SVG (and CSS).

**Can I create a responsive SVG path without stretching or distorting the stroke?**

Comment: So you want the space around the white to be the same on the sides as with the top and bottom? As a percentage, I assume? I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do

Comment: Yes, I don't want the stroke width being distorted.

Comment: Can then use javascript to add the attribute dynamically rather than manually adding to every path in case of more complex SVGs

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As covered in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1304602/2065702), you should use [`vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/painting.html#NonScalingStroke) to keep the stroke width the same regardless of the scaling. [**Updated demo**](http://codepen.io/Zeaklous/pen/ONGJab)